# initializing a 3d char array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having issues with initializing my array of char[][][] and displaying it of which i have never really used but must use now so I'm not very familiar with it. the array is used in a booking system where a user e asks for say a cabin on deck 1 column 1 row 1 which should be an "i"

Header File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Ship
{
public:

Ship()
{
}

char cabins[13][4][1];
void setArray();
void showArray();
};
```

Comment: Are you just making up syntax?  Where did you come up with this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote this

```
for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j< 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++)
        {
    cabins[13][4][1] =  (("b" "i" "i" "b")
```

Which would iterate across all the characters in the array, and then try to assign the entire array that slot, if it worked, or was valid C++.

I'm not sure what "(("b" "i" "i" "b")" is supposed to be, but you seem to have missed some C++ fundamentals. What you actually want is something more like

```
char cabins[13][4]; // only needs to be 2d.

void Ship::setArray()
{
    cabins = {
       { 'b', 'i', 'i', 'b' },
       { 'b', 'i', 'i', 'b' },
       ...
    };
}
```

[edit: I hit return early, working on the laptop, sorry]

This too would not work. If the array definition here is to be persistent, you'll need to store it somewhere.

Here's a complete single-compilation-unit example of how you might solve it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // for memcpy

class Ship {
public:
    Ship() {}
    char m_cabins[4][4];
    void setArray();
};

void Ship::setArray() {
    static const char defaultCabinLayout[4][4] = {
        { 'b', 'i', 'i', 'b' },
        { 'b', 'i', 'i', 'b' },
        { 'w', 'i', 'i', 'w' },
        { 'w', 'i', 'i', 'w' },
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(m_cabins) == sizeof(defaultCabinLayout), "defaultCabinLayout does not match m_cabins");
    memcpy(m_cabins, defaultCabinLayout, sizeof(m_cabins));
}

int main() {
    Ship s;
    s.setArray();
    std::cout << "cabins[0][0] = " << s.m_cabins[0][0] << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use curly braces `{` `}` around values in initialization, not parentheses.
Add commas in between too!
And also, what is the array's definition doing inside your loop?
Oh, my...

Comment: and characters not strings.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot that can be missed in this program... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be this...

```
cabins[k][j][i]
```

In you're loop if you are trying to initialize it at certain indexes.

for instance.

```
cabins[1][1][1] = 1;
```

This is setting the value at deck 1 column 1 and row 1 equal to 1.

When you are looping through those 3 `for` loops you are incrementing through `i, j, k`

I don't really understand how you are assigning values per index so.... if you elaborate more on that I could help you a bit more.

Comment: There's no reason for this to be a 3-dimensioned array - it's a 2d array of chars. The 3rd dimension is from his imagination.